# PIVOT ignoring some values on MS SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, pivot

([Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/0a464/4) is the link to SqlFiddle with complete data and queries.)

I have the following table[image: PIVOT inpit] which I want to pivot basing upon the `[Rank]` column.

I have written a straightforward code for doing so:

```
SELECT Url, [1] AS Source1, [2] AS Source2 , [3] AS Source3
FROM Urls
PIVOT
(
    MIN(Source)
    FOR [rank] IN ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5])
)
AS dtpvt
```

In my data there is always a row with `rank == 1`, so I expected that the first column will never contain any `NULL` values, but I get rather strange result:

[image: PIVOT output]

So, I have multiple `NULL`s in my first column. I actually expected the values with `rank == 1` to go to the first column, with `rank == 2` to the second and so on, but the result table actually puzzles me.

What am I missing here? How can I get my expected result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All columns that aren't mentioned in the pivot are used to generate unique rows in the result. Note that you mention neither `Url` nor `Popularity` in the `PIVOT` and so the distinct values of those columns are used to work out the resulting rows.

To eliminate `Popularity` being used, use a subquery to eliminate it:

```
SELECT Url, [1] AS Source1, [2] AS Source2 , [3] AS Source3
FROM (select Url,Source,Rank from Urls) u
PIVOT
(
    MIN(Source)
    FOR [rank] IN ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5])
)
AS dtpvt
```

(Also, it's a good job you included the fiddle since your question failed to mention the `Popularity` column at all, and without knowing about that extra column, the question doesn't make sense)